# html dom parsing, asp.net framework v 3.5

Tags: vb.net, reference, .net-3.5, html-parsing

When I add htmlagilitypack/microsoft.mshtml to my references, it says library contains no public members.

Are there any ways to parse DOM structure in 3.5 ?